# VERY BASIC: How to inline social media logos on a header

Tags: html, css, header

I just started trying to learn how to code 4 days ago. I've been learning html and css to start. I want to try and put everything that i've learned together, by creating a website for myself.

I'm trying to create a fixed header. On the left side of the header I want to incorporate my social media accounts by linking them to the little icons of each website. However, they stack on top of eachother even though I have them set at inline.

I need help getting them to align next to each other, and put them all into the same size.

I appreciate any help that I get!

Here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/Users/Hunter/Documents/Website(CSS).css"> 
        <title>Hunter's Website</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="top">
            <div class="social">
                <div class="row">
                    <div id="twitter" class="col-md-4">
                        <a href="http://twitter/#.com"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/twitter_circle_color-512.png" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="instagram" class="col-md-4">
                        <a href="http://instagram/#.com"><img src="http://www.roommagazine.com/sites/default/files/pictures/Instagram-circle-icon-150x150.png" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="quora" class="col-md-4">
                        <a href="http://quora/#.com"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.startups.fm/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/quora-logo.jpg" /></a>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="jumbotron">
        </div>
        <div class="pictures">
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS Code:**

```
div .top {
    height: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    display: inline;
}

#twitter #instagram #quora {
    height: 5px;
    width: 5px;
    z-index: 10;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    margin: 2px;

}

.jumbotron {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-image: url("insert grad picture")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem here

```
#twitter #instagram #quora
```

this means that you are looking for a div that has id=quora inside a div called instagram inside a div called twitter .
what you are looking for is this

```
#twitter,#instagram,quora{
/*your style*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.col-md-4 {
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this format, or give your divs a class that is unlikely to change. The problem is you are targeting the parent div with .top. Use the code below to target the correct children divs.

```
.social .row div{ display: inline;}
```

This would also work

```
#twitter, #instagram, #quora{ display: inline;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap, as the CSS and HTML kind of indicates, you should be fine just by adding this to the CSS:

```
.col-md-4 img {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;    
}
```

And you should probably take off the `div .top`, or at least make it just .top and take off any height measurements if they're not in percentages. With Bootstrap that could cause some issues. Use `min-height` and `max-height` if you must specify something static.

Also take a note on what others already stated, if you decide to use #twitter and ID's just like that, use commas to separate them in CSS. Otherwise you end up nesting them, and it becomes a problem.